# compat-openmpi for centos 8 or redhat 8

Tags: package, centos, redhat, rpm, openmpi

I have found compat-openmpi packages for centos 7

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-rpm-bin-package-in-redhat-linux-8

or

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/compat-openmpi16-1.6.4-10.7.2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

However, I need one for redhat 8 or centos 8.  Any ideas of where to find packages for compat-openmpi for centos 8 or redhat 8?  Also how to do go about installing this package?

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL there are only `openmpi` and `openmpi-devel` packages. Probably `compat` packages is dropped by RH. And the reason is version you mention is 1.6.4 and current version is 4.1.1